# Align subfloats to the top of the figure

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats

I want to put a listing next to a schematic in one figure. The template of the journal, I am writing my article for, suggests using subfloats.

Here is my latex sourcecode,

```
\lstset{
    numbers=left,   
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true
    numbers=left,% display line numbers on the left side 
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,% use small line numbers 
    numbersep=10pt,% space between line numbers and code 
    breaklines=true,% automatic line breaking     
    columns=flexible,
    frame=tb,
    mathescape=true,
    xleftmargin=2em,
    framexleftmargin=2em,
    morekeywords={input, output, clb, pinlist, subblock, tcon, parameter}
}
\newsavebox{\tconlist}
\begin{lrbox}{\tconlist}% Store first listing
\small
\begin{lstlisting}
.parameter $sel_0$
.parameter $sel_1$

.input i0
pinlist: i0p
.input i1
pinlist: i1p
.input o0
pinlist: o0p

.output o1
pinlist: o1p

.tcon i0p o0p $\neg sel_0$
.tcon i0p o1p $\neg sel_1$
.tcon i1p o0p $sel_0$
.tcon i1p o1p $sel_1$
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat{\usebox{\tconlist}}
\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth, trim = 60mm 80mm 145mm 35mm, clip]{2x2crossbar_schema}} 
\caption{A schematic of a $2{\times}2$~crossbar switch functionality represented by 4 TCONs and the corresponding TCON netlist}
\label{fig:2x2crossbar}
\end{figure}
```

This results in the following image,
[image]

How can I align the two floats to the top of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `minipage`s are vertically centered. That is, their anchor point is given halfway up/down the `minipage`. Since you're placing the `lstlisting` inside a `minipage`, it makes sense that it's anchored in the middle.

What you're looking for is either a `[t]`op or `[b]`ottom-aligned `minipage`:

```
\newsavebox{\tconlist}
\begin{lrbox}{\tconlist}% Store first listing
\small\begin{minipage}[b]{<len>}% Perhaps also try [t]
\begin{lstlisting}
%...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
```